# REST API Call in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, curl, urllib

I am trying to make a REST GET call to fetch some information from a URL which needs authorisation. I eventually wanted to make some POST calls. But trying to understand Python's REST capabilities using GET as I am new to Python.

As I understand, requests module seems to be the best one to use for REST calls. However, due to organisational restrictions, we are not allowed to install extra modules and hence I am looking for alternate solution and found two approaches as coded in the screenshot1.

[image: Python REST API Calls]

But both these approaches doesn't do anything. testRESTAPI1() calls simply prints **None** as output while testRESTAPI2() throws an error as captured in screenshot2

[image: Error Message - testRESTAPI2]

The authentication details are correct and when I use simple curl on linux cli, it works all perfect and fetches the result. However, through python this is not working. May I know where this is going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Should you not be doing .post instead?

Comment: @ProNinjaCat I need to make GET call as well and hence written the code for the same.

Comment: I feel that depending on how the authorization takes place, you would need to do a  POST request in order to actually have the code authenticate your account.

Comment: Copy & paste your actual code & output.  **Do not post pictures of text.**